# C# program stops on startup

Tags: c#, .net

I have made a c# program in VS2017. I have compiled it in Framework 4.5 and runs perfectly in my computer with Windows 10. I put it on a Win7 32 bits computer, and crashes on startup. That computer has the Framework 4.6.2 installed. I use some references in my project: Newtonsoft.Json and VLC.DotNet (which has 3 separates dll) all of the dlls have the "Copy Local" set to true. Nevertheless, I have this error (Sorry, the SO is in Spanish):

```
  Nombre del evento de problema:    CLR20r3
  Firma del problema 01:    CreativaTV.exe
  Firma del problema 02:    1.0.0.0
  Firma del problema 03:    594417a6
  Firma del problema 04:    Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops
  Firma del problema 05:    2.1.0.0
  Firma del problema 06:    58dcd6cf
  Firma del problema 07:    e
  Firma del problema 08:    1e
  Firma del problema 09:    System.IO.DirectoryNotFound
  Versión del sistema operativo:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Id. de configuración regional:    11274
  Información adicional 1:  0a9e
  Información adicional 2:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Información adicional 3:  0a9e
  Información adicional 4:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

I will translate what I think is critical information:

```
Name of the problematic event: CLR20r3 
Problem signature 03: 594417a6 
Problem signature 04: Vlc.DotNet.Core.Interops 
Problem signature 09: System.IO.DirectoryNotFound
```

Comment: run the program with procmon fro sysinternals. You can see what files / dirs its trying (and failing) to find

Comment: @pm100 you mean this software? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx

Comment: yes i do ............

Comment: You appear to be using a .NET Core library. If so, make sure your Windows 7 environment [meets the prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/windows-prerequisites) for .NET Core.